# New favorites alert shown despite no favorite updates

Tags: bug, status-completed, favorites-notifications

Occasionally when I visit stackoverflow.com I see the "new favorites" alert.
Clicking this takes me to the recent page where there are either no changes since
my last visit or I have new reputation. Rarely are the questions I have marked
as favorites actually updated.

FWIW I got the alert just now on SO, but had new rep and a new comment. Does
this alert really mean "you have updates of some kind"? If so, then the subtle
orange envelope suffices. If it really should indicate favorite activity then
it seems a bit overzealous.

Comment: In the entire time I've been on SO, I've never seen the notification mechanisms work in a reliable and consistent manner.

Comment: This is, in fact, by design: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51947/allow-users-to-opt-out-of-all-favorite-notifications

Comment: Yeah, wow. This is **so** annoying. Stack Overflow is a programming / software engineering Q&A site, so it's just the audience to wince at this broken and/or useless implementation and get hacked off every day it tells us our favorites have changed. Grrr! It's also broken on the non-programming sites as well, which is just the audience to just be confused and not care *why* it's broken. **Please fix it or remove it.**

Answer (score 7):

I got the exact same problem. Nearly every time I log onto stackoverflow, the "You have changes to your favorites" notification shows. But when I click it I just get an page with an empty list, and it seems there really was not changes to my favorites.

Do not confuse this with the "[Allow users to opt-out of all favorite notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51947/allow-users-to-opt-out-of-all-favorite-notifications)" issue that is now solved. I do want to receive notifications when my favorites changes, but I get the notification when there seems to be no change at all to my favorites.

Comment: I am experiencing this problem constantly. Going to opt out of notifications until they actually work.

Comment: this is because edits to your favorites aren't currently showing up in the tabs, but are counted for the purposes of lighting the envelope.

Comment: @Jeff: Then it ought to either be shown as "Edited" or not light the envelope. The combination of the two is irritating.

Comment: Either way an action that leads to an empty list is not of much use to anyone